# How to use Minkowski Sum on convex hulls of obstacle in robotics?

Tags: geometry, robotics

Let's say I have a convex obstacle given by the vertices in their convex hull. Specifically, the obstacle is given by points {(1,0), (2,0), (2,2)}. In addition, I have a robot which is just a unit square, so we could represent it with coordinates {(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)}.

Now what I want is to get the convex hull of a new obstacle that has been expanded from all sides by 1 such that any point inside the convex hull would be infeasible and I can quickly tell that it's not a legal position of the robot.

I've been told that we can use the Minkowski sum to solve this problem, I don't see it. If I take the Minkowski sum of my two sets, I get

{(1,0), (2,0), (2,1), (1,1), (2,0), (3,0), (3,1), (2,1), (2,2), (3,2), (3,3), (2,3)}

This isn't convex, but we could easily remove the internal points. But despite this, it seems I've only expanded the right side of this obstacle not all sides. I could potentially also potentially use the unit squares in all quadrants of the euclidean space, but will this always work? How do I know that the convex hull of the Minkowski sum with 4 unit squares indeed defines the illegal configuration space?

Comment: Note, in reality, I have a circular robot with radius r. Please do let me know if there's a more direct way to do this than using a square.

Comment: What tools do you have available? Can you compute the distance to the convex hull?

Comment: Your calculation of the Minkowsky sum is wrong — in particular, the Minkowsky sum of any two convex sets will itself be convex.

Comment: What is wrong with my calculation? I just used the definition. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something, but I don't quite understand what.

Comment: You need to take the Minkowski difference of the obstacle and the robot. This will be the convex hull of the points $(0,0), (0,-1), (2,-1), (2,2), (1,2)$. Then as long as the bottom left corner of the robot does not lie in this convex hull the robot will not touch the obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for:

Suppose $C$ represents the convex obstacle and $R$ represents the robot floorplan
if the robot is located at the origin.

If you move the robot to $x$ then the robot flooorplan is $\{x\}+R$.

Then the robot flooorplan intersects the obstance **iff** $\{x\}+R$ intersects
$C$ **iff** $x \in C-R$ (the Minkowski difference).

It doesn't really change anything, but if the robot is symmetric about the origin then $R=-R$ (as a set) and so 
$C-R = C+R$.

Note that if $R$ is the convex hull of $r$ points and $C$ is the convex hull of $c$ points then $C-R$ is the convex hull of $c \cdot r$ points.